# MongoDB: How to get all documents by the keys from another collections without de-normalization?

Tags: mongodb, denormalization

Imagine we have two Collections: one of `topics` and one of `posts`. And we have a `user._id`:

```js
topic  {
    _id, // topicID
    userId
}

post {
    topicId
}

user {
    _id
}
```

How in MongoDB get all the `posts` by specific `user` (*without storing `userId` in the `post`*)?

```js
(post.topicId === topic._id) && (topic.userId === user._id)
```

Comment: collect all topic id in an array from topics collection and then use $in query in posts collection against topcId to get all posts.

Comment: @user10, yeah thanks! Is there a more efficient way? Or what is the most efficient way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)** operator to do a left join on the unsharded `topic` collection, then filter the resulting documents using a **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** pipeline. You may need to use the **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter)** operator on the topics array to include only the subdocuments that match the given user id condition. The following demonstrates this approach:

```
db.post.aggregate([
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "topic",
            "localField": "topicId",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "topics"
        }
    },
    { "$match": { "topics.userId": user._id } },
    {
        "$project": {
            "topics": {
                "$filter": {
                    "input": "$topics",
                    "as": "item",
                    "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$item.userId", user._id ] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, that what I was looking for. Only as `$lookup` adds array it should be `"topics.0.userId": user._id` in match.